Sidekiq::Testing.fake! and retrying jobs
I'm writing a test that invokes Sidekiq::Testing.fake!. The test is designed to assert behavior that occurs when a particular job raises an error.
Normally, the job is supposed to retry up to 5 times if an error is raised, but after I call .drain on the job's Worker class, the job runs once and then just disappears. I tried calling Sidekiq::RetrySet.new and Sidekiq::DeadSet.new to see if the job was moved to either of those queues, but the size of each is 0. I also checked the worker class's .jobs Array, and it's also empty.
Am I missing something? Is there a way to replicate retry behavior when using Sidekiq::Testing.fake!?

You aren’t missing anything. You are trying to test Sidekiq functionality. Your tests should test your functionality. Sidekiq::Testing does not provide integration testing functionality.
